# Are App Permissions confined to specific Activities?

Tags: android

In the main Activity, I asked the User for permissions for using Camera.
However, I wanted to use the Camera in another activity let's SecondaryActivity
I asked for permissions like this in one activity :-

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) 
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED, 1);
}
```

and checking in other activity just before starting the service.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SecondaryActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // Do Something }
```

Since, both `this` here are different, will I have to request permissions for different activities differently or not ?

Comment: User can at any time revoke your camera permission in settings. So basically you DO have to check if you have the permission, but you do not have to ask for it each time.

Comment: Permissions are not strictly related to 1 activity or the other, they're for the entire app

Comment: You could have saved writing this question just by trying out your code. If it reaches the code in the if-block in the second activity it means that granting it in the first works for the second.

Comment: How does the permission demanded from one context gets shared to other context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are granted or revoked for the whole application, not a specific activity.

However, it is still best practice to always check if you have a permission, right before you need it. Users can grant and revoke permissions at runtime. Allthough revoking a permission will lead to a restart of your activity.